Maximal eigenvalue of a real symmetric Toeplitz matrix, especially in the limit
Hi: In a research project I stumbled upon real symmetric Toeplitz matrices of the following type:
$$
A_n = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & \cdots & a_n\\
a_2 & a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_{n-1}\\
a_3 & a_2 & a_1 & \cdots & a_{n-2}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
a_n & a_{n-1} & a_{n-2} & \cdots & a_1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
In my case, the sequence $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots $ is positive, strictly decreasing and $a_n \to 0$.
I am interested in the 2-norm ( = maximal eigenvalue ), or lower bounds on this norm, and especially its limit as $n\to \infty$. This is because I am looking to ‘push’ this norm above some given value, so a (somewhat sharp) lower bound would be nice.
I am aware that there’s extensive literature on these type of matrices, but I find it hard to find exactly what I am looking for. I was wondering if someone could point me to something that may be useful for me. Thank you!

The classical bound $S/n$ where $S$ is the sum of all the entries gives a lower bound: $$\frac{S}n = a_1 + 2 \left( \frac{n-1}n a_2 + \frac{n-2}n a_3 + \ldots + a_{n} \right) \leq \lambda_{\max} (A_n).$$
For large $n$, this bound gets sharper and sharper.
To see why, in the special case of Toeplitz matrices, one often considers the associated Fourier series; here, due to $A_n$ being hermitian, this Fourier series defines a real function. In our case, it can be written as
$$f(x) = a_1 + 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n+1} \cos(nx), \quad x \in [0,2\pi).$$  This function gives some pretty simple bounds on all eigenvalues, for all $A_n$. Indeed, for all $n \geq 1$ and all $\lambda \in \mathrm{Spec}(A_n)$, one has
$$\min f \leq \lambda \leq \max f.$$ (See for instance Lemma 4.1 in https://ee.stanford.edu/~gray/toeplitz.pdf .)
As all Fourier coefficients are positive, the series has its maximum when all the cosines are $1$; that is, for $x=0$, finally obtaining both upper and lower bounds for the maximal eigenvalue:
$$ a_1 + 2 \left( \frac{n-1}n a_2 + \frac{n-2}n a_3 + \ldots + \frac 1 n a_{n} \right) \leq \lambda_{\max} (A_n) \leq a_1 + 2 \sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n. $$ In the limit $n\to \infty$, we see that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \lambda_{\max} (A_n) = a_1 + 2 \sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n.$$
(If the sequence $a_n$ is not square summable, we do not need to define the Fourier series; in that case, the classical lower bound already implies
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \lambda_{\max} (A_n) = a_1 + 2 \sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n=\infty.)$$

The matrix has strictly positive entries, hence the Perron-Frobenius theorem applies.
The eigenvalue $r$ with maximal absolute value is real and satisfies
$$\min_{i}\sum_{j}c_{ij}\le r \le \max_{i}\sum_{j}c_{ij}.$$
Since the sequence $(a_i)_1^{\infty}$ is decreasing, the minimal row sum is
$$a_1+\dots+a_n$$
This is one possible lower bound of the norm. However, I didn't benefit from the special shape of the matrix.
